JSON code for Change Text to Red when value is $1000 or greater
I am new to JSON and am looking for some assistance. I created a SharePoint list with a calculated column set to automatically add selected cells to yield the total. My goal is to have the cell turn Red, and words Bold, if the Total is $1000 or Greater.
I attempted to use conditional formatting however, there seems to be some restriction when it comes to formatting a Calculated Column. The calculated column name does not appear on the format screen.

If you are trying to do this on a list view, you can access the Format Column command from the field header.

From the conditional formatting panel, you can set the rules (no json knowledge required!)

UPDATE
If the calculated field doesn't display in the dropdown for editing the rules, it might be because the display format is set to currency. This seems to be a quirk of the rules editor, and I could reproduce your issue.
The workaround is to change the field output type to number, implement the conditional formatting, and then go back set the display format to currency.


Thank you for sharing. One of the issues I am having is that for my Calculated Column, when I attempt to add a conditional formatting rule, I do not see the column as an option to select. For example, in your image, you indicated "if Calc1 is greater than 1000". I do not see an option to choose my designated calculated column name in order to add that criteria.

Looking at my first screenshot, do you see your other columns in the drop down list (Choose Column)? Have you tried setting up a separate test list to see if the behaviour is the same for that as well?

I think I've figured out why you can't see the field in the rules editor. I'll update my answer

Hi Paul, the issue continues to persist with both options selected. Any other thoughts on how to resolve?

Actually, disregard, it does work! I just realized I was updating the wrong column. Thank you for your help on this!
